# UFT is not finding the objects in IE

Tags: hp-uft

I have this code to find WebEdit objects. It works just fine finding objects on that page in chrome. It does not find the objects in IE. I get objCount = 2 for chrome and I get objCount = 0 for IE.

I have a function which opens the URL in specific browser.

```
Public Function OpenApplication(myURL, brType)
    systemUtil.Run brType,myURL
End Function
```

I have a function which simply finds number of webedits objects.

```
Public Function NoOfWebEdits()
       set basepage = Browser("micclass:=Browser").Page("micclass:=Page")
       Set oEdit = Description.Create()
       oEdit("micclass").Value = "WebEdit"
       oEdit("Visible").Value = "True"

       Set basepage = basepage.ChildObjects(oEdit)
       objCount=basepage.count
       NoOfWebEdits = objCount
End Function
```

My sample script for chrome:

```
OpenApplication("examplesite.com", "chrome.exe")
NoOfWebEdits
```

This works just fine. My page has two objects. NoOfWebEdits returned 2 as expected.

My sample script for IE:

```
 OpenApplication("examplesite.com", "iexplore.exe")
    NoOfWebEdits
```

It does not work. NoOfWebEdits returned 0 but I had two objects on the page. Based on my debug, I think UFT is still looking for chrome browser. UFT may not even looking at IE. How can I fix it? Is there way I can update my NoOfWebEdits function by saying activate IE browser and then count the number of objects?

---

**Update # 1:**

I had this code:

```
systemUtil.Run "iexplore.exe","www.google.com"
Print Browser("micclass:=Browser", "index:=0").GetROProperty("version")
```

I ran the code while chrome was open. I got "chrome 71.0"

I closed the chrome browser. I ran the code again and I got "IE 11"

Comment: In order to troubleshoot your code I would suggest first of all making sure you're working with the correct browser. `Print Browser("micclass:=Browser").GetROProperty("version")`

Comment: I updated my post.

Comment: Does the object spy work on IE?

Comment: With IE, you can be quite sure IE will crash if you attempt to address it using UFT if initialization is not yet complete. Imho, there is no safe way to check for this, you can only workaround the by adding a delay of >= 4 seconds just below the Systemutil.Run line. I know WebApps that do strange things that interfere with UFTs IE addon in a way that it crashes 100% of the time without the delay.

Comment: My prev comment does not mean that this is the cause for the problem. If spying IE does not work, close and re-open it. Does it work now?

Comment: Plus, I faintly remember a problem where the property "visible" is displayed as true/false in the OR, but is 0 or 1 at runtime, with 0 never being present so you cannot check for it. Not sure if it was IE-specific. Try using (for diagnosis only) a unique property value instead of visible. Does that work for both browsers? If so, forget about the visible property and look for something else...

Comment: Object spy works just fine.